# Why does Angular2 TestBed's compileComponents can't find my templates?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I have a component, let's call it MyComponent. It's using my.component.html as the templateUrl.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-component",
  templateUrl: "./my.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my.component.css"]
})
```

I am writing a test (spec) for this component. Since, it'susing an external template, I am calling **compileComponents** after **configureTestingModule**.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
}));
```

While running the test, I am getting this error -

> Failed to load my.component.html

The app runs absolutely okay with **npm start** and serve the templates as it should be. It's just the test which is failing with given setup. What I am doing wrong?

I am following [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/).

Comment: did you try providing full path of template url? Do you see any other error, something start with 404?

Answer (score 1):

In my webpack test config I had only **awesome-typescript-loader**, I just had to add **angular2-template-loader** along with.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Looks like this `loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?removeComments=true', 'angular2-template-loader']`

Comment: next time include the script you included so other can solve too